# Авторизация через токены rest api

Tags: rest, authenticationtoken

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На скринах выше документация к api findface security, пытаюсь сделать авторизацию, но не могу понять откуда берется токен и как его получить. Ответом приходит 401, то есть, как и сказано, нет авторизации. Первый опыт работы с rest api, что я делаю не так?

Вот мой запрос, вместо троеточия должен быть токен?

```
fetch('http://172.16.3.98/auth/login', {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: { Authorization: '...' },
    })
        .then(response => {
            console.log(response)
        })
        .catch(err => console.log(err))
```

Также хотел сделать в postman, но не понимаю, что нужно вписать в key и value:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: судя по первому скриншоту токен должен выглядеть так: `{ Authorization: `Token ${токен}` }`

Comment: Да, это я понимаю, но где взять его? Я же не должен его сам придумать?

Comment: токен вы должны получить, у меня в приложении пользователь авторизуется при помощи логина и пароля, в случае успеха в ответ приходит токен который участвует в дальнейших запросах к api